# Do search in azure files inside documents

Tags: azure, file, search, storage

I have an account in azure and in this I have a storage account. 
I would like to do searches within the documents that are inside the folders in this storage.
I have already seen that in blob it can be done but in blob it is not possible to create folders or any structure.
In short, how can I do searches within the files in azure storage?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/search/) was designed to do exactly this.

You point it at your blob storage, let it index your files and then use the API to interrogate the files.

In terms of folders, in Azure Storage Gen 2, you can have hierarchical namespaces that mimic folders. Alternatively you can use Azure Data Lake storage, which has the concept of folders however the former is preferred.

The quickstart for Azure Search can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/search/search-create-service-portal) and there is a free tier you can trial (limited to 3 indexes and 10,000 documents).

Comment: Hi Murray, Could you give an example in java how to do it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with java really. There is a REST Api endpoint that you consume after you have indexed your files.  You can use curl, Java C#, Pyton etc.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/

Comment: Hi Murray, I have tried it in several ways and it has been impossible to make a viable code to access the json that should return the search, would you have an example of how to connect, no matter the language?

Comment: Here is the formal java example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-java

Answer (score 0):

As Murray already mentioned, Azure Search is exactly what you're looking for.

You can find a good tutorial here: [Azure Search Code walkthrough](https://github.com/Azure/LearnAI-Bootcamp/blob/master/lab02.1-azure_search/0_README.md).

Comment: Hi Axxeption, could you post a example of what i can do these searchs?

Comment: Hi! Do you mean an running example as a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, resolved.

```
    URL url =SearchServiceHelper.getSearchURL( URLEncoder.encode("searchstring", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));

            HttpsURLConnection connection = SearchServiceHelper.getHttpURLConnection(url, "GET", "KEY");
            JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(connection.getInputStream());
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("value");
            jsonReader.close();
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println(url);

            JsonArray jsonResult = jsonArray;
            List<Structure> docList = jsonToDocument(jsonResult);

-------------------
Where :
private static final String _searchURL = "https://%s.search.windows.net/indexes/%s/docs?api-version=%s&search=%s&searchMode=all";
public static URL getSearchURL( String query) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        Formatter strFormatter = new Formatter();
        strFormatter.format(_searchURL, "searchservicenameonly", "index", "api-version", query);
        String url = strFormatter.out().toString();
        strFormatter.close();

        return new URL(url);
    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------
public static HttpsURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url, String method, String apiKey) throws IOException
    {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("api-key", apiKey);

        return connection;
    }
```

You have to create a structure to save the data that the search returns.